# Accessing a method of a parent class in the sublass

Tags: python, oop

i am new to OOP.

i have a parent class with a method that i wanna access in my subclass. But i cannot figure out the right syntax for that. I cannot find a clear cut example anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Members in the base class are simply available to the subclass as well (unless they are overwritten):

```
class Base:
    def example (self):
        print('This is in the base class')

class Subclass (Base):
    def test (self):
        self.example()
```

An object of type `Subclass` can now access `example` directly or indirectly:

```
>>> x = Subclass()
>>> x.test()
This is in the base class
>>> x.example()
This is in the base class
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def output(self):
        print self.name



class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        Parent.__init__(self, name)
        self.age = age

    def output(self):
        super(Child, self).output()
        print self.age


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Parent("wy")
    b = Child("zhang", 10)
    a.output()
    b.output()
```

You can try this code.